# Log WCF Service Calls with Parameter information

Tags: .net, wcf, logging

I've been using the Service Trace Viewer to analyse the WCF service calls that are made in our application but I really need to see the parameter values that are passed to the service methods?  Is this possible?  I've tried turning the logging to max output but still can't see anything :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you enable message tracing, you should get all the details of both the call (including the XML representation of your message sent out) as well as the answer:

```
<system.diagnostics >
  <sources>
    <source  
        name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" 
        switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" >
       <listeners>
          <add name="yourTrace" 
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
               initializeData="C:\Logs\YourMessageLog.svclog">
             <filter type="" />
           </add>
       </listeners>
     </source>
  </sources>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
   <diagnostics>
       <messageLogging 
             logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" 
             logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
             logMalformedMessages="true" 
             logEntireMessage="true"
             maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000" maxMessagesToLog="500" />
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This should create a file called "YourMessageLog.svclog" in a directory "C:\Logs" (which must exist beforehand!) and which you can view with the WCF Service Trace Viewer.

What you'll see here is the **XML representation** of the message going out and the response coming back in - your parameters will have been wrapped into your XML structure here. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I had tried setting the message logging up in this way before but was doing it on the server rather than the client so it wasn't working as I expected.  Cheers for pointing me the right way :)

Comment: The type for the listeners should be System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener

Comment: hi I am using on my WCF service DataContract and a function that get int. PLEASE I need to see the parameters that passed to the WCF service on the trace viewer I ca see only the hedear what about the body??