# WCF service attribute to log method calls and exceptions

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, custom-attributes, aop

I have a requirement to log each method call in a WCF service, and any exceptions thrown.  This has led to a lot of redundant code, because each method needs to include boilerplate similar to this:

```
[OperationContract]
public ResultBase<int> Add(int x, int y)
{
    var parameters = new object[] { x, y }
    MyInfrastructure.LogStart("Add", parameters);
    try
    {
        // actual method body goes here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MyInfrastructure.LogError("Add", parameters, ex);
        return new ResultBase<int>("Oops, the request failed", ex);
    }
    MyInfrastructure.LogEnd("Add", parameters);
}
```

Is there a way I can encapsulate all this logic into an attribute `MyServiceLoggingBehaviorAttribute`, which I could apply to the service class (or methods) like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
[MyServiceLoggingBehavior]
public class MyService
{
}
```

---

**Note #1**

I realize that this can be done using [Aspect-oriented programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133569/how-to-log-method-calls-on-targets-marked-with-an-attribute), but in C# the only way to do this is to modify bytecode, which requires the use of a third-party product like PostSharp.  I would like to avoid using commercial libraries.

**Note #2**

Note that Silverlight applications are the primary consumers of the service.

**Note #3**

[WCF trace logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178256/log-wcf-service-calls-with-parameter-information) is a good option in some cases, but it doesn't work here because, as noted above, I need to inspect, and in the case of an exception change, the return value.

Comment: Have you tried WCF tracing?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm not fluent in WCF tracing -- may have fulfilled the logging requirement, but in any case I don't think it would enable wrapping each method call in a try-catch and returning a `ResultBase<T>` object upon exception.

Comment: Yeah, sorry; I hadn't noticed that requirement. Not sure how wise that is, but...

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'd be curious to hear what specifically troubles you about the relative wisdom of that approach.  Actually, at first I had a solution that passed uncaught exceptions (`IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults`), and modified the outgoing messages using `IDispatchMessageInspector` so that Silverlight could display the message and not the dreaded "NotFound".  But I scrapped it because of some weird problems adding the custom endpoint behavior, and because of some legacy client code that relied on the `ResultBase` approach. (I may post that solution here too, when I have a minute.)

Comment: Mainly, did you notice that you didn't specify you were using Silverlight? I presume you're dealing with REST services? Otherwise, my first objection is that you're not using SOAP faults.  I would loathe the fact that you're asking your callers to check return codes to determine whether or not there's a problem. Exceptions (and therefore faults) are much cleaner.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to encapsulate this kind of logging, using the [extensibility points built into WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx).  There are actually multiple possible approaches.  The one I'm describing here adds an `IServiceBehavior`, which uses a custom [`IOperationInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ioperationinvoker.aspx), and does not require any web.config modifications.

There are three parts to this.

1. Create an implementation of `IOperationInvoker`, which wraps the method invocation in the required logging and error-handling.
2. Create an implementation of `IOperationBehavior` that applies the invoker from step 1.
3. Create an `IServiceBehavior`, which inherits from `Attribute`, and applies the behavior from step 2.

#### Step 1 - IOperationInvoker

The crux of [IOperationInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ioperationinvoker.aspx) is the `Invoke` method.  My class wraps the base invoker in a try-catch block:

```
public class LoggingOperationInvoker : IOperationInvoker
{
    IOperationInvoker _baseInvoker;
    string _operationName;

    public LoggingOperationInvoker(IOperationInvoker baseInvoker, DispatchOperation operation)
    {
        _baseInvoker = baseInvoker;
        _operationName = operation.Name;
    }

    // (TODO stub implementations)

    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
    {
        MyInfrastructure.LogStart(_operationName, inputs);
        try
        {
            return _baseInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyInfrastructure.LogError(_operationName, inputs, ex);
            return null;
        }
        MyInfrastructure.LogEnd("Add", parameters);
    }
}
```

#### Step 2 - IOperationBehavior

The implementation of [IOperationBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.ioperationbehavior.aspx) simply applies the custom dispatcher to the operation.

```
public class LoggingOperationBehavior : IOperationBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.Invoker = new LoggingOperationInvoker(dispatchOperation.Invoker, dispatchOperation);
    }

    // (TODO stub implementations)
}
```

#### Step 3 - IServiceBehavior

This implementation of `IServiceBehavior` applies the operation behavior to the service; it should inherit from `Attribute` so that it can be applied as an attribute to the WCF service class.  The implementation for this is standard.

```
public class ServiceLoggingBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
        {
            foreach (OperationDescription operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            {
                IOperationBehavior behavior = new LoggingOperationBehavior();
                operation.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. This is what I have done in a past project too. It works well.

Comment: It fails in operation.Behaviors.Add when I have more than one endpoints. Probably we should get operations collection only from 1st endpoint or check whether this behavior is already added...

Comment: @McGarnagle Unfortunly is not working in my case. Behaviour is just never gets called...

Comment: Check if is there any other `ServiceBehaviours` attached to the service. That might be the case.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) library with its [Audit.WCF](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.WCF/README.md) extension. It can log the WCF service interaction and is compatible with async calls.

All you need to do is decorate your WCF service class or methods with the `AuditBehavior` attribute:

```
[AuditBehavior()]
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{ ... }
```

The WCF extension uses an `IOperationInvoker` implementing `Invoke` and `InvokeBegin`/`InvokeEnd`. You can check the code [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.WCF/AuditOperationInvoker.cs).