# WCF services hosted in IIS, what are options to add additional data to IIS logs

Tags: wcf, iis

I have WCF services hosted in IIS, The IIS loges shows only the svc file name.

What are my options to add additional information to IIS logs, such as web method name or selected parameters?

Thank you,

**Update 1**

I surely know there are many options to log many aspects of WCF runtime outside IIS logs. That is out of the scope of this question. This question laser focuses on WCF on IIS and IIS logs. The reason for such focus is that When you don't have any access right on an existing production LOB WCF app server with strict change management policies (such as finance, sensitive gov etc..), things become different than your local dev machine. IIS logs become a practical option since extracting IIS logs is usually a well-established process in such type of production environment.

I am aware that this is possible with custom behaviours. I wonder if there is any article explain the details.

Therefore:

- Please avoid tagging this article as "duplicate",  unless the other SO question is WCF IIS Log related question.
- The focus of the answers should stay on WCF on IIS and IIS logs

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF service attribute to log method calls and exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655541/wcf-service-attribute-to-log-method-calls-and-exceptions)

Comment: None in IIS, as that's just the HTTP side of things. See [WCF service attribute to log method calls and exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655541/wcf-service-attribute-to-log-method-calls-and-exceptions) to log it using a custom logging framework, I'd use log4net.

Answer (score 0):

With the right configuration, you can see all requests and response from the server, in the svc log. That includes the method parameters and return values. More information you find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx