# How can I trace and log performance and call on my Web API requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nlog

I just herited of a very bad Web API code in C#. I need to improve it but I don't know where to start. There are plenty of classes and the code is a nightmare. I also think part of code is never used.

I would like to count the number of time each request is called and what time each request last. I would like to log all my result in a table. In one or two days I could have a clear view of what I the most used and what take time. Client are complaining about that.

I use Nlog for log and a simple Stopwatch to calculation of performance. What do you suggest? I know it's better to use Filter and attribute for traces but how can I log and trace performance like this?

```
// GET api/Item/5
public Item GetItem(string id)
{
    // I don't use string.Format in my real code. This is just for this example.
    logger.Trace(string.Format("Request: GET api/Item/{0}", id));
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    Item item = context.Items.Single(i => i.Code == id);

    sw.Stop();
    logger.Trace(string.Format("Response: GET api/values/{0}\r\nElpased={1}\r\rn{2}", id, sw.Elapsed, response));
```

I found previous information here

Thanks to

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/log-message-request-and-response-in-asp-net-webapi

[Exact time measurement for performance testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/969290/196526)

*Of course all these Trace and performance jobs will be activated or deactivated from my config file. For NLog it's built in. For the Stopwatch I plan to build something. I don't plan to keep this alive all the time on production*

Comment: Resharper won't help here. Resharper cannot detect unused request on runtime.

Comment: Attribute base logging Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655541/wcf-service-attribute-to-log-method-calls-and-exceptions

Comment: Ok, Read my question Offir Pe'er. It's about writing code, not using a tool.

Comment: As controllers are created per request you could create a master controller which starts the logging in it's constructor and finish it in a deconstructor. Then you dont have to add loggin code in each method and still get a view on the overhaul performance.

Comment: @Prathyush This where I'm lost. Each article I read suggest different approach. Use ActionFilter, now use IOperationInvoker, use DelegatingHandler,... Seriously I still prefer writing my log manually at the beginning and end of each of my methods.

Comment: @B413, depends upon comfort and understand of the any approach you can decide which approach is correct in given time frame. As in past I had also faced the same scenario and at last ending manual logging what you have mentioned. Before reaching star lets reach moon first ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DelegatingHandler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers).

> A base type for HTTP handlers that delegate the processing of HTTP response messages to another handler, called the inner handler.

[image]

Injecting in pipeline allows to capture place before and after request processing in your controller.

```
public class MonitoringDelegate : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
    var watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    watcher.Stop();

    //log/store duration using watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds

    return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @set answer, you should register the delegate.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MonitoringDelegate ());

        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at profilers. This more general approach. We use [Ants performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/walkthrough).