# Exception with ServiceKnownType when the WCF method returns a collection

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have a base class `Fallible<T>` and several derived classes `Success<T>`, `Failure<T>` and `BadIdea<T>` which are to be used in the return value of a WCF service call.

As I [previously discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965504/serializationexception-when-returning-custom-classes-from-a-wcf-service), in order to get this to work, I needed to decorate the WCF service method with the `ServiceKnownType` attribute as follows...

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Fallible<Patient>)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Success<Patient>)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(BadIdea<Patient>)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Failure<Patient>)]
public Fallible<Patient> GetPatient(int id) {
  return new Success<Patient>(new Patient {ID = 1,FirstName = "Jim",Surname = "Spriggs"});
}
```

This works fine. However, I now want a WCF service method that returns a collection...

```
public List<Patient> GetDischargedPatients()
```

Following what I did before, I tried decorating this, but no matter what combination I tried, I get exceptions. Here is the full combination of what I tried...

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Fallible<PatientOverview>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Success<PatientOverview>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(BadIdea<PatientOverview>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Failure<PatientOverview>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Fallible<PatientOverview[]>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Success<PatientOverview[]>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(BadIdea<PatientOverview[]>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Failure<PatientOverview[]>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<Fallible<PatientOverview>>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<Success<PatientOverview>>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<BadIdea<PatientOverview>>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<Failure<PatientOverview>>))]
public Fallible<List<PatientOverview>> GetDischargedPatients() {
  return new Success<List<PatientOverview>>();
}
```

As you can see, I've thrown everything in there (except what actually works!), but I still get the original exception I got before discovering the `ServiceKnownType` attribute...

> "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:5448/PatientsService.svc.
>   This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be
>   due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting
>   down). See server logs for more details."

Inner exception:

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

Inner exception:

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote host."

Inner exception:

> "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

WCF really isn't giving me any information about what's going wrong here. I tried using `ServiceKnownType` with various combinations of the return type, including `Fallible<Patient[]>` and `Fallible<List<Patient>>` but it didn't help.

Anyone any ideas what I need to do to return a collection?

Comment: How many patient do you return? may be it's a size problem !
How do you polymorphism in your case ?

Comment: @Esperadoce I've tried this with an empty list, one patient, etc. Based on what happened last time I did this (see the linked question), the issue isn't the data, it's to do with the serialiser not being able to serialise the data. That's an issue of it knowing about the types, which is why I added the `ServiceKnownType` attribute.

Comment: Can you try to make ServiceKnowType in the interface instead ?

Comment: I think that you have a problem in Polymorphism Serialization i think i have a link to give you that will show you the path to do it and what you should avoid

Comment: @Esperadoce Not sure what you mean by using `ServiceKnownType` in the interface. You mark the service call itself with the attribute, as I have in the working example. The only difference here is that I want to return a collection, not a single item. I'd be interested to see that link. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'I tried decorating this as before'? in regards to returning `List<Patient>`

Comment: @Scrobi I updated the question to include the code I tried. I did this in stages, but at one point added everything that I could think of, which is what you see above. Thanks

Comment: The problem seems very similar to this one: [XmlInclude : List and array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36308317/3744182).  Both `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` will generate identical contracts for `List<T>` and `T []`.  One solution here, as there, would be to introduce a surrogate type that distinguishes the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried to replicate your issue with a trimmed down version of your code and ended up with this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
     //Get a patient's data
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Fallible<Patient>))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Success<Patient>))]
    Fallible<Patient> GetPatient(int id);

     //Get a list of Patients
    [OperationContract]
    List<Patient> GetPatients();

    //Get a list of patients
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Fallible<List<Patient>>))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Success<List<Patient>>))]
    Fallible<List<Patient>> GetSpecificPatients(string type);
}
```

and the implementation of the service:

```
public class Service : IService1
{
    public Fallible<Patient> GetPatient(int id)
    {
        return new Success<Patient>() { Value = new Patient() { Name = "Scott Robinson" } };
    }

    public List<Patient> GetPatients()
    {
        List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>();
        patients.Add(new Patient() { Name = "Scott Robinson" });
        patients.Add(new Patient() { Name = "Darryl Robinson" });
        return patients;
    }

    public Fallible<List<Patient>> GetSpecificPatients(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Fallible":
                return new Fallible<List<Patient>>() { Value = new List<Patient>() { new Patient() { Name = "Scott" }, new Patient() { Name = "Darryl" } } };              
            default:
                return new Success<List<Patient>>() { Value = new List<Patient>() { new Patient() { Name = "Scott" }, new Patient() { Name = "Darryl" } } };
        }
    }
}
```

However I do not get the error.

Looking at your code I can see that your `GetDiscardedPatients` returns `Fallible<List<PatientOverview>>` but none of the 'ServiceKnownTypes` are of this type. Have you tried:

```
ServiceKnownType[Fallible<List<PatientOverview>>]
ServiceKnownType[Success<List<PatientOverview>>]
...
public Fallible<List<PatientOverview>> GetDischargedPatients() {
  return new Success<List<PatientOverview>>();
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm baffled! I did try `Fallible<List<PatientOverview>>` etc (not as I mistakenly typed into my edited answer where I put List<Fallible<PatientOverview>>`) and had the same problem. However, I just copied your code and it worked. Not sure what the difference was, but it's working now. Thanks very much.

Comment: hahahaha - glad you got it working. You can break mine if you add `ServiceKnownType[Fallible<Patient[]>]` the deserialization doesn't like having both attributes at the same time.

Comment: The only thing is that I didn't have them both at the same time originally. I originally used `List<Patient>`, but got an error about `ArrayOfPatient`, which is why I switched to `Patient[]`. The code I added to my question was a last-ditched attempt to get it working by throwing everything in! Still don't know what I did wrong, but I'm not going to worry too much. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(CommandServiceHelper))]
public interface IPatientService
{
     //Your interface methdos
}
```

this is the helper class that will be called each time that WCF need to know a type.

```
public static class CommandServiceHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        //Return a list of type that your service will need to know 
    }
}
```

And if you need more detail and explanation you can check [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/morgan/2009/08/05/polymorphism-in-wcf/) by **Mebyon Kernow.**

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am already using that method. I only posted the version using `ServiceKnownType` to make the posted code easier to read. My problem is knowing what type(s) to include in the list.

Comment: Just to clarify, the code I showed originally works fine for returning a single item, I'm having difficulty working out what types to include when returning a collection.